# Concat selected values from multiple dropdown lists and bind to a field in database

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding

Someone help me please.

Here's the thing, I need to create three dropdown lists each for day, month, year. Once these are selected, after clicking a button, the three selected values need to be concatenated and bound to a date column in a database table.

If its a single control, I know I can just use "<%# Bind("Date") %>" but how do i do this.

I've been searching extensively for a week now.

I tried this 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa581787.aspx but it's not working

This is my first question in this forum so please excuse me if I neglected any etiquette

Thanks,
Sam

Comment: Do you mean, after clicking a button, these three values need to be represented by a DateTime object, and this object is the value in a database table?

Comment: Please clarify what you're trying to do in regards to 'binding' the result of the three controls. Are you trying to set a parameter on an ObjectDataSource? Something else?

Comment: That's exactly what i want. I want to set a parameter but I don't know how to do this in codebehind. "Bind" just binds the control directly,right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One not-so-straightforward but easy way to solve this is to have an `<asp:Hidden />` field that's actually bound to the date column and it's value is initialized to day+month+year from the dropdowns. The `<asp:Hidden />` could be updated when these drop downs are changed. So, when you you are ready to insert or update the datasource, you'll get the value from this `<asp:Hidden />` which has the date value that's in-sync with the combo boxes.

Comment: Oh that looks quite good. Thanks. But isn't there a more elegant solution than this. This seems like a common kind of problem. What do you say? Thanks for your reply

Comment: I have always used a textbox with some javascript date picker for date selections. One way to make the above mentioned solution clean is to define a usercontrol with the dropdowns and have one public property that exposes the date and inside of the usercontrol you manage the date formation essentially eliminating the hidden field. This would be a much better option if you have to reuse the same logic in several other places.

Comment: Oh that's really cool. I'll try to implement and get back to you. Thank a lot